# Execute bash commands that take input from php

Tags: php, bash

I have a php script that I use to execute bash commands.

That bash command does not take argument at start, i.e.

```
ssh root@ip
```

However, when this command is executed, later it requires input from user.

So how can I accomplish this with php?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`popen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) which returns a file handle:

```
$handle = popen("ssh root@ip", "w");
fwrite($handle, "This is send as stdin\n");
// ...
pclose($handle);
```

Example:

```
<?php
  $handle = popen("cat - > a.txt", "w");
  fwrite($handle, "hello world\n");
  // ...
  pclose($handle);
?>
```

Will create `a.txt` with contains `hello world`.

Comment: ssh root@ip , after executing this command it will next ask for the password for the remove server, why will i need a file handle for that ? Sorry if i don't understand your answer. @andlrc

Comment: @Ethical So that you can send an answer, to the process. `popen` stands for process open, and returns the process's standard input to `$handle`.

Comment: Thank you for your response it some how helped. But the command I am working with requires 2-3 user inputs, for that popen is not working, any other alternatives or suggestions? @andlrc

Comment: @Ethical Can't you just call `fwrite` three times or write a multiline string: `fwrite($handle, "a\nb\nc\n")`

Comment: Yes i actually called it three times and tried with \n as well, but it still don't work. It gives the input only to one of the intermediate steps. @andlrc